# Find document range same day from mongodb use GetMongo processor by NiFi

Tags: date, mongodb-query, apache-nifi, mongodb-compass, apache-nifi-toolkit

I want to get the documents in mongodb for the day. I tried querying with **mongo compass** the code works. The code is as follows:

```
{
  "time_created": {
    "$gte": new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    "$lt": new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999))
  }
}
```

But when I use the above query code with the "query" property of GetMongo, I get the following error message:

```
Verification Results
Perform Validation
Component is invalid: 'Query' validated against '{ "time_created": { "$gte": new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)), "$lt": new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)) } }' is invalid because Query is not a valid JSON representation due to Unrecognized token 'new': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String)"{ "time_created": { "$gte": new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)), "$lt": new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)) } }"; line: 3, column: 16]
```

[image]

[image]

I tried converting to JSON format but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "time_created": {
    "$gte": { "$date": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'')}" },
    "$lt": { "$date": "${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'23:59:59.999\'Z\'')}" }
    }
}
```

and

```
{ 
    "time_created": { 
        "$gte": "${now():toDate():format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'')}",
    }
}
```

but it not work.

Please help me, thanks.

Can you help me convert mongodb query to json format working with GetMongo ?

```
{
  "time_created": {
    "$gte": new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
    "$lt": new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999))
  }
}
```

Give me another more suitable solution ?

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Nifi's getMongo Query field doesnt support EL. So i created a stored function in MongoDB for my dynamic query and called it from Nifi.

Create function in Mongodb:

```
db.system.js.insertOne({
   _id: "find_data_by_date_range",
   value : function(created_time) {
    var fromDate = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    var toDate = new Date(new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 999));
    if ((created_time >= fromDate) && (created_time <= toDate)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
});
```

Query Nifi:

```
{"$where": "find_data_by_date_range(this.time_created)"}
```

It is worked!